# Java, combining two integers to long results negative number

Tags: java, long-integer, bit

I am trying to combining two integers to a long in Java. Here is the code I am using:

```
Long combinedValue = (long) a << 32 | b;
```

When `a = 0x03` and `b = 0x1B56 ED23`, I am able to get the expected value (`combinedValue = 13343583523` in long).

However, when my `a = 0x00` and `b = 0xA2BF E1C7`, I get a negative value, `-1567628857`, instead of `2730484167`. Can anyone explain why shifting an integer 0 by 32 bits causes the first 32 bits become `0xFFFF FFFF`?

Thanks

Comment: Use `long` instead of `Long` as well for the `combinedValue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` is negative, too.  That's what that constant means.  What you probably *want* is `((long) a << 32) | (b & 0xFFFFFFFFL)`.

Comment: Don't you want to cast `a` to long first?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes fixed.

Answer (score 3):

When you OR `(long) a << 32` with `b`, if `b` is an `int` then it will be promoted to a `long` because the operation must be done between two values of the same type. This is called a widening conversion.

When this conversion from `int` to `long` happens, `b` will be sign extended, meaning that if the top bit is set then it will be copied into the top 32 bits of the 64 bit long value. This is what causes the top 32 bits to be `0xffffffff`.